# ORA-00936: missing expression with CASE WHEN subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00936

I am getting the error `ORA-00936: missing expression` with the `CASE WHEN` statement below. possibly due to the `rownum`? I have tried `LIMIT 1` to no avail and also `TOP 1` (but that isn't a thing in Oracle SQL)

Basically, the `CASE WHEN` below is to catch when the sub query returns more than one value (v_date) and just pick one of the two duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.v_type AS Type, 
g.f_group AS Group, 
g.v_no AS Number,
g.v_date AS Date, 
g.a_year AS Year, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT v_date 
                 FROM glv
                 WHERE v_type_reference = g.v_type AND v_no_reference = g.v_no AND g.com = com) = '1' 
     THEN (SELECT DISTINCT v_date 
           FROM glv
           WHERE v_type_reference = g.v_type AND v_no_reference = g.v_no AND g.com = com) 
     ELSE (SELECT v_date 
           FROM glv
           WHERE v_type_reference = g.v_type AND v_no_reference = g.v_no AND g.com = com AND rownum = 1) 
     END AS LLD
FROM glv g
WHERE g.a_year = '2015'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your count and select clauses mixed up; this:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT v_date
```

should be

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v_date)
```

Some of your aliases are reserved words, but I assume you've changed those for posting, as you'd get an ORA-00923 with exactly what is in the question.

As an aside, if your `a_year` field is a number then `'2015'` shouldn't be in quotes; similarly in your count comparison, `'1`' should just be a number, not a string.